# password encryption in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

Is there a way to pass encrypted password using liquibase against db2 database? Currently liquibase accepts clear text password and I would like to run liquibase using encrypted password. Please share your recommendations on this?

use variables to hide the password but that is not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like db2 does support this, and liquibase can support passing in JDBC driver properties by specifying a `driverPropertiesFile` argument to Liquibase.